# Why is it "very bad practice" to override new when using Moose?

Tags: perl, constructor, overriding, inline, moose

From the [Moose::Manual::BestPractices](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod#Never_override_new) page:

> Overriding `new` is a **very bad practice**. Instead, you should use a `BUILD` or `BUILDARGS` methods to do the same thing. When you override `new`, Moose can no longer inline a constructor when your class is immutabilized.

**My question is why is this considered very bad practice?**

I thought an "inline" constructor just meant that the constructor was defined in the same package as the class.  If this is true wouldn't it mean that if you overrode `new` within that package the constructor would still be considered an "inline" constructor?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  I don't fully understand the concept of what it means for a constructor to be "inline."

---

The reason I came across this question is because I'm creating a script that builds a list of objects.  If a user attempts to create a new object that is identical to one in the list I want to stop `Moose` from creating a new object and just return a reference to the existing one.

When a new object is created I want to push it onto the list and return the new object.  When an attempt is made to create existing object the existing object should be returned and not pushed onto the list.

```
# Some pseudo code showing the logic of what I attempted
around BUILDARGS => sub {
    my ($orig, $self, %args) = @_;

    # loop through objects in list
    for my $object (@list) {

        # if $args used to define the new object
        # match the arguments of any object in the list
        # return the matched object

        # I want this to directly return the object
        # and skip the call to BUILD
    }

    return $self->orig(
        # Insert args here
    );
};

sub BUILD {
    my ($self) = @_;

    # I don't want this call to happen if the object already existed
    push @list, $self;
}
```

When creating a new object I attempted to use `BUILD` to push it onto the list once it is created.  The problem is when I attempted to create an existing object and use `BUILDARGS` to return the existing object doesn't seem to stop `Moose` from calling `BUILD` which attempts to push the object onto the list.

The only way I was able to get around this was to override `new` and have it return the existing object without creating a new one.

```
# Some pseudo code showing the overridden constructor
sub new {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;

    # loop through objects in list
    for my $object (@list) {

        # if $args used to define the new object
        # match the arguments of any object in the list
        # return the matched object
    }

    # Build the object
    my $self = bless {
        # Insert args here
    }, $class;

    # Add the object to the list
    push @list, $object;
}
```

Overriding `new` worked, but if it really is such a horrible idea, as the `Moose` documentation seems to suggest, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another issue with overriding `new`, other than `Moose` not being able to *in-line* the constructor.  I discovered that if you override `new`, it prevents `Moose` from being able to make attributes "required" when calling the constructor.

---

For example if you override `new` and define a class with an attribute like so:

`has 'var' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', => required => 1);`

`Moose` will allow you to create a new instance of this class without passing it a value for `var`.

---

I found a workable solution for what I want to do, at least I think it's workable.  I don't really need the speed of an *in-line* constructor (I'm not creating millions of objects), but I do need the ability to "require" attributes.  If you use the `around` function provided by Moose you can essentially override new, without preventing `Moose` from being able to "require" attributes.

ex:

```
around new => sub {
    my ($orig, $class, %args) = @_;

    # loop through objects in list
    for my $object (@list) {

        # if $args used to define the new object
        # match the arguments of any object in the list
        # return the matched object without calling new
    }

    # Create a new object
    my $self = $class->orig(%args);

    # Add it to the list of objects.
    push @list, $self;
};
```

This approach still gives you the warning about not being able to create an *in-line* constructor, but at least it will function correctly.

*Note: adding `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable('inline_constructor' => 0);` to the end of your package will suppress this warning.*

Answer (score 0):

*In-lining* a subroutine means to copy its code at the point of the call instead of inserting a subroutine call. This is much faster because it avoids the overhead of collecting the parameters and any local variables on the stack as well as the the call and return operations. It is impossible if the class hasn't been declared immutable because any mutation may mean that the constructor has to change and so no longer can be inserted in-line

Comment: I do declare the package immutable, but I was required to add `inline_constructor => 0`.  Is there any way to achieve the functionality I want without fully overriding `new`?  Or if that is not possible, is there a way to ensure that the overridden `new` will still be "inline?"

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I suggest you take a look at [`MooseX::Role::Flyweight`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::Role::Flyweight) which adds an `instance` method that behaves the same as `new` but will return a previously-created object if it has been called before with the same parameters

Comment: That does look like a potential solution; however it is not a part of the standard distribution of ActivePerl.  Where I work the network security is very strict and we are unable to download anything so I am unable to get any modules from cpan.  Even using the cpan command to install modules fails.  Is there a way to do this without a non core module?

Comment: @tjwrona1992: That's a silly rule. Can you download the distribution and install it from that, or aren't you allowed USB drives either? You could print off the source at home and type it in?!

Comment: Well I can get modules, I just have to go through IT and get it approved then they need to make a work order and install it themselves... Then anyone else who would want to use my code would need to do the same so its just really a hassle.  I guess if I had the source code I could save it in the same folder as my module and package it in a way that people could use it.  I've done that with a couple things but that just seems unnecessary.

Comment: Also using `MooseX::Role::Flyweight` would change the way users interact with the module and would require them to use the `instance` function rather than `new`.  I would really prefer to keep the interface with users as basic/familiar as possible so people using it will know how to use it without reading a bunch of documentation.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Okay, well pure Perl modules *are* the source files, and this one's [literally 40 lines of Perl](https://metacpan.org/source/STEVENL/MooseX-Role-Flyweight-1.03/lib/MooseX/Role/Flyweight.pm). I suggest you either pretend you wrote it yourself or read and understand it so that you can implement something similar that lets you keep the `new` method. Essentially it keeps a hash of the objects that have been created, using a JSON-encoded version of the parameters for the keys